# Open Graph разметка на сайте Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, разметка, opengraph

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю нет так и почему OG разметка на сайте Битрикс не работает? Пишу разметку для компонента news.detail. Для этого сначала в файле result_modifier.php прописываю:

```
<?php
$this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array(
    "NAME",
    "DETAIL_PICTURE",
    "PREVIEW_TEXT",
    "DETAIL_PAGE_URL"
));
?>
```

Затем пишу в файле component_epilog.php:

```
<?php

    $APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="og:title" content="'.$arResult['NAME'].'"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="og:description" content="'.ucfirst($arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT']).'"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="og:site_name" content="Название сайта"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="og:url" content="'.$host.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false).'"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<link rel="canonical" href="'.$host.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$arResult['DETAIL_PAGE_URL'].'"/>'); 
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="og:image" content="http://site.ru'.$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC'].'"/>');


$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="twitter:title" content="'.$arResult['NAME'].'"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="twitter:description" content="'.ucfirst($arResult['PREVIEW_TEXT']).'"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>');
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta name="twitter:site" content="@site"/>');     
    $APPLICATION->AddHeadString('<meta property="twitter:image:src" content="http://site.ru'.$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC'].'"/>');

?>
```

Когда пересылаю эту ссылку через мессенджер, то все берется, кроме картинки. И это еще можно пережить. Но если размещаю ссылку в фб, то там отражается полная шляпа с информацией вообще с другой страницы. Хотя при просмотре полного кода страницы все эти мета-теги корректно выводятся. Что делаю не так, никак не могу понять :(

Comment: У вас получилось решить проблему с Open Graph?
У меня сейчас стоит задача внедрить её на свой сайт в разделах каталог (разделы и элементы) и новости (элементы). С учетом всех обновлений, какие действия нужно сделать, чтобы заработала разметка Open Graph для последующего использования для социальных сетей?

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы проверить какие проблемы возникают с разметкой вам надо пользоватся (например )откладчиками перепостов, у FB  так же есть такой инструмент 
[Инструменты и поддержка](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

Для проверки разметки для `Twitter` можете воспользоватся `Twitter card validator` вот [ссылка](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)

Comment: спасибо большое, не знала об этих инструментах! но все-равно не понятно почему так происходит. Подозреваю, что ошибка в написании этих тегов в шаблоне битрикса

Comment: Ошибки могут быть от многих причин, если имеются ошибки при сканировании в данных инструментак показывает в чём ошибка...

Comment: какие ошибки у вас выдаёт ?

Comment: здравствуйте. Выдает такую ошибку : Inferred Property
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
И такие же относительно тайтл, дискрипшн, изозображения

Comment: а также просит явно указать  FB:app_id

Comment: Информация "вообще с другой страницы" может означать, например, то, что в кэше фейсбука эта другая страница ранее открывалась по тому же адресу. Кэш через инструменты можно сбросить. Ну и, конечно, посмотрите итоговый код страницы -- там вообще какие теги? Возможно, где-то с урлом проблема, например, слеша не хватает.